# I want to connect to bridge using infiniband

Tags: centos7, infiniband

I want to connect the physical port (ib0) to the bridge (bro).

I am constructing kvm, but the physical port of infiniband to the virtual bridge
I want to connect, but I could not do it well.
Please tell me who understands.

OS: centos7

I did:

```
nmcli con add type bridge ifname br0
nmcli con modify bridge-br0 bridge.stp no
nmcli con modify bridge-br0 ipv4.method manual ipv4.address "192.168.10.1/24"
nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname ib0 master bridge-br0
nmcli con del ib0; reboot
```

result:

```
[root@node2 bridge]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.000000000000       no
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not possible to associate an Ethernet bridge with an IPoIB interface. But why do you want the IPoIB interface to be on the bridge in the first place? If you are interested in using RDMA in the VM, you should use SR-IOV or PCIe passthrough. If you only need IP forwarding between the VM and the rest of the IPoIB subnet, you can use NAT.

Comment: I'm happy to help.